# In Ninja Forms (Wordpress), how can i set the "From:" field?

Tags: wordpress, email, ninja-forms

In the email sent after the user fills out the form, I want the "**From:**" field to be filled with the user's entered data, ie: a "pretty printed" email address in of the form ["Johnny Appleseed" jhonny@apple.com]. currently it will only fill the From: field with my own address. I do NOT want to use the "**Reply-to:**" field.

Please let's not talk about why i should not do this, just help me achieve my goal if you can, thanks!

Comment: There are already a couple of fields for this within the form settings (Ninja Forms > [Your Form Here] > Emails & Actions > Email Notification > Advanced.) You'll need to turn on NF's "Dev Mode" to see them though.

Answer (score 3):

i learned that if you enable "Dev Mode", then these fields become available.

Comment: Indeed this works, but it is still rather hidden: You have to open the email action (with the cog) and then pick Advanced near bottom. The "From" is available under that after enabling dev mode in settings.